# Can merging master into develop in GitFlow ever cause conflict?

Tags: git, merge, git-flow, git-merge-conflict

I am wondering if using gitflow and merging master into develop will ever cause a conflict.  I intend to make this 'git merge master' into develop command an automatic, non-interactive process, so if there is a conflict, it will fail since it would need human interaction.

I am using GitFlow and changes that get applied directly to master is a version bump which bumps the version, commits, then changes the version to a snapshot version.  For example, master may have 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT as the version.  If we version bump it, version will change to 1.0.2 and then we make a git commit.  Then we change the version to 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT and then commit this.  So every version bump causes two commits (see mvn version updater).

Periodically, I want to merge the latest version from in master into develop by calling git merge.  This will take the version change but it will also take any other changes found in master and not in develop.  I *believe* this shouldn't cause any conflicts since everything master has, develop should also have, because we merge develop into master.

I have tested file renames, editing files that are going to get deleted, and lots of edits to the same file, but under this model I cannot get a conflict after merging from master to develop.

Is there any way to make a conflict here?  Would there be any issue trying to automate the merge master-into-develop process? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Yes!

I see multiple questions / issues here we need to talk about:

(1) In the `git-flow` [created and documented by nvie](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) there is no merge from `master` into `develop` but rather a merge from a (let's just use version `1.0.2` in this example) `release/1.0.2` branch into `master` and `develop`.

(2) This `release/1.0.2` branch is meant to be the location where you would adjust your version. It will then automatically appear on `develop` since you merge `release/1.0.2` into `develop` after every release anyway. No need to periodically update from `master` then.

(3) The `master` branch only contains merge commits, nothing else. It's just an ordered list of all releases.

(4) You could run into merge conflicts in both cases since `develop` is continuously worked on (assuming you are not all alone working on the whole project) while you work on `release/1.0.2`. If changes in the same lines are made, merge conflicts could (but don't necessarily need to) arise.